# Comando para deixar scrollbar fixed

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber se tem algum comando css para deixar o scroll do type[number] fixo pois só aparece quando o mousse está em cima.
Queria que ficasse o tempo todo com as duas fechas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Testado no Chrome e Firefox:

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: muito obrigada, deu certo, mas só funcionar no chrome?

Comment: No firefox está funcionando também!

Comment: Só não funciona no IE e Edge

Comment: No Edge não tenho certeza, mas o type="number" no IE não exibe as setas, certo?!

Comment: Exato, fiz teste nos 5 navegadores (Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE e Edge) e só IE e Edge que não funciona

Comment: ok, sem problemas.. o publico do site utiliza mais o Chrome
obrigada

Comment: @n.danzi de nada!